# React Native async await call return error

Tags: react-native, async-await, expo

Function outside await : return error Can not use keyword await
Help me please...

```
I18n.defaultLocale = 'tr'
await AsyncStorage.getItem('locale').then((value) => {
 I18n.locale = value        
}).done();


I18n.fallbacks = true;
I18n.translations = { en, tr };

const currentLocale = I18n.currentLocale();

export function strings(name, params = {}) {
  return I18n.t(name, params);
};

export default I18n;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do something like this with await/async :

```js
var getItem = async function() {
  // await can be used here
  await AsyncStorage.getItem('locale').then((value) => {
    I18n.locale = value        
  }).done();
}
```

and call it like this :

```js
getItem(); // sync
```

or

```js
await getItem(); // in another async function
```

Edit : With async function you can "do the same things" than a none async function. It's just `await` that is requiring particular wrapping.

Comment: thank you  getItem(); call other files ?
a.js - getitem function
b.js - call a.js call getitem function ?

Comment: just export/import the function if you want reuse it in another file

Answer (score 0):

An `async` function can contain an `await` expression that pauses the execution of the `async` function and waits for the passed Promise's resolution, and then resumes the async function's execution and returns the resolved value.

> Remember, the `await` keyword is only valid inside `async` functions.
>   If you use it outside of an `async` function's body, you will get a
>   SyntaxError.

you don't need to use `then` when using `async/await`,

for more details see [async function on MDN Web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)